# Angular - TitleCase - Can we have words like 'in' non-capitalised?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have seen TitleCase used for capitalizing each word of a string which is useful, however...

I am wanting to output movie titles that have been stored as all **lowercase**. I could use TitleCase, but this would not give the appearance that people usually expect.

For example, the movie title (in lowercase):

> the assassination of jesse james by the coward robert ford

I could use TitleCase for output:

> The Assassination Of Jesse James By The Coward Robert Ford.

However when seen in print in either magazine or on movie posters the **O** and **B** of **'of'** and **'by'** are never capitalized.

Is there a simple method by which I can get the look I am wanting to achieve, other than simply using `{{movie.title | titlecase}}`?

I know that I could create a dictionary and search for the keywords within the strings, but I am wanting something potentially simpler...

Comment: You can write your own pipe that wraps the titlecase pipe and then converts to lowercase whatever you need.

Comment: Oh? Could you possibly direct me to a source so I can read up on it?

Comment: [Angular Guide on Pipes](https://angular.io/guide/pipes)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could write your own pipe that capitalizes every word EXCEPT the ones you don't want capitalized.

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core'

@Pipe({ name: 'titleCaseExcept' })
export class TitleCaseExceptPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: string): string {
    if (!value) return value; // safeguard

    // regex to find all words EXCEPT the ones we don't want capitalized
    let words: RegExp = /\b(?!of|by|the)\w+/g;
    // capitalize the first letters of said words
    let newVal = value.replace(words, (match) => {
      return match.replace(/^\w/, (word) => word.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + word.substr(1).toLowerCase());
    })

    // always capitalize the first character of newVal
    return newVal.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + newVal.substr(1);
  }
}
```

Add words you would like excluded to the regex as you see fit.

Comment: any word that starts with 'of', 'by', 'the' will not be converted to first letter uppercase with this solution.

Answer (score -3):

Using the default pipe is recommended if you are using for display purpose only, since the framework would handle the case conversion.

Comment: But if I use `| titlecase` I will get all capitalised words such as `Of` when I am wanting lowercase `of`

Comment: In that case I would also suggest the solution provided by @oram

Comment: Wrong recommendation given in answer.